# How to get tweets from a user's account using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, twitter

I want to get the tweets by the people a user follows (i.e tweets on the user home page.) Is there any way to get them?

Comment: I've seen numerous websites that can parse tweets and display them in their own way. I guess the Twitter API is just what you want: http://dev.twitter.com/.

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/pborreli/pJgyu/?

It gets a number of tweets for a given user.

Comment: Could you possibly explain why only one tweet shows up whilst you use `tweets:4`?

Comment: I thinks that's because of the user's lack of tweets. I changed it to my username and it shows 4 tweets.

Comment: That's weird - on the 'regular' Twitter website jQuery has multiple tweets. Your code does show several tweets when using another username, though.

Comment: It's just using the Twitter search API like so: http://search.twitter.com/search.json?callback=?&rpp=4&q=from:jquery, which only returns 1 tweet for jquery, so the code looks sound, if there is an issue it's with Twitter's API.

Comment: It's actually using this URL: http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?callback=jsonp1344969812617&screen_name=jquery

Comment: Just for anyone that stumbled upon this, Twitter's v1 API no longer works and thus this code won't work.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a basic solution that might help you get started:

```
<ul id="tweets">
    <li>Loading tweets...</li>
</ul>
```

And in your JavaScript, assuming you have jQuery available:

```
var url = 'http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?callback=?'
        + '&screen_name=yourusername&count=4';

$.getJSON(
    url,
    function (data)
    {
        var $tweets = $('#tweets');
        $tweets.empty();
        if (data.length !== 0) {
            $.each(data, function (i, tweet)
            {
                if (tweet.text !== undefined) {
                    $tweets.append($('<li></li>', { text: tweet.text }));
                }
            });
        } else {
            $tweets.append($('<li></li>', { text: 'No recent tweets' }));
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: This is no lover available as v1 of api is deprecated and all endpoints require auth